# Xcode: Create a group of outlets

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode4, iboutlet

This is just a quick question, I have lots of outlets in my code that need to be hidden initially and I want to make it so that in my viewDidLoad I only have to say something along the lines of `colourObjects.hidden = YES;` rather than individually going through and declaring if they are hidden or not i.e. `redColourObject.hidden = YES;
blueColourObjects.hidden = YES;
greenColourObjects.hidden = YES;` I would find it very grateful to know if this is possible and how you do it!

Thanks for any help
Hugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBOutletCollection is what you need:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *stuff;
```

You can drag as many outlets as you want in it and they'll be there. You can also keep the original references for other purposes. then

```
for (UIView *view in self.stuff) {
    [view setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: I assume the first goes in the header file and the second in the implementation file! Where would I declare the different outlets in the NSArray? (sorry for the extra questions my age and inexperience  lacks me in ability to program)

Comment: the @property goes in the interface definition, which is usually in the header. It could also be in the .m if it was an extension. You don't need to declare each outlet, you just get all the UIViews (in this example, could be other types) that you drag to that outlet in the interface builder populated into that array after the nib is loeaded.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but there is not a way to do that. You would have to declare that individually.

What you could do I put them all into one UIView and then hide the UIView which would hide everything in in the UIView.

Comment: Please refer to @Fernando Mazzon answer, it is possible, indeed.

Comment: @TomRoggero I did not see anything in the UIKit framework which is why I made the assumption. Sorry.